# Accessing a datagridview from another class

Tags: c#

I have an application that is working, but Im wanting to organise it a bit better by moving some of my methods into their own classes in separate files as currently i have one long mega list of code. This is something i have not tried before.

I created the separate class in its own file and checked i could access it ok (which I can) but I have found as it uses a datagridview from the main form (that the original method was from) it now no longer can access said datagridview from the new class.

What is the best way to get round this? Can i bring the whole datagridview in as a parameter to the method and then get access to it? Or do i have to pass each property of the datagridview one parameter at a time?

The method basically applies formatting to the datagrid as well so it needs to be able to update back to the main form also.

```
public class GridFormat
    {
        public void applyFormat()
        {
            //Method to Apply formatting to main grid

            int complete = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                string header = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                if (header == "Completed" || header == "jlComplete") { complete = i; }
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                if ((Convert.ToString(row.Cells[complete].Value) == "True"))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could provide the datagrid as a parameter either to `applyFormat` or you store it in a property of `GridFormat` if that datagrid is specific to your `GridFormat` instance.

Comment: I did try passing datagridview1 as a parameter to applyFormat method using 
applyFormat(Control dgrid1)
but this gave me an error "Control does not give a definition for ColumnCount" on my for loop. Or is that not how you are suggesting i do it?

Edit - This is how i passed it
GridFormat gridformat = new GridFormat();
gridformat.applyFormat(dataGridView1);

Comment: why Control? use type DataGridView or at least cast it to a DataGridView

Comment: ahhh! OK that seems to have worked, I took the "control" type from another, similar stackoverflow response in my initial search for an answer. That has fixed most of it but for some reason the "Color.Gray" is giving me a "Color does not exist in the current context" error

Comment: you're probably mising a using directive. add using System.Drawing;   or assign System.Drawing.Color.Gray. Without providing a namespace Color.Gray is unknown